# Ходы фигур в шахматах

Tags: c#, wpf, шахматы

Создал шахматное поле и разрабатываю ходы. Поле сделал с помощью грида и заполнил кнопками. Каждая отличающаяся фигура имеет собственный тег. Я понял как в такой системе я могу двигать те же пешки, но вот как двигать фигуры по типу ладьи, ферзя и т.д. Как ограничить их ход, в том плане чтоб они не перепрыгивали через другие фигуры

```
int x1=Grid.GetRow(sender as Button);
        int y1=Grid.GetColumn(sender as Button);
        go=Convert.ToInt32(((Button)sender).Tag);
        if(pos==1)//пешка
        {
            if(x1==x+1 && y1==y && go==0)//ход пешки
            {
                ((Button)sender).Content=1.ToString();
                ((Button)sender).Tag=1;
                ((Button)vernut).Content="";
                ((Button)vernut).Tag=0;
            }
            else if((go==11||go==12||go==13||go==14||go==16||go==15) && ((x1==x+1 && y1==y-1) ||(x1==x+1 && y1==y+1)))//сруб пешки
            {
                ((Button)sender).Content=1.ToString();
                ((Button)sender).Tag=1;
                ((Button)vernut).Content="";
                ((Button)vernut).Tag=0;
                int a=Convert.ToInt32(belie.Text);
                a+=1;
                belie.Text=a.ToString();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Вы не можете ходить по координатам x:"+x1.ToString()+"  y:"+y1.ToString());
            }
        }
        else if(pos==2)
        {
            if((x1==x+1 && y1==y||x1==x+2 && y1==y||x1==x+3 && y1==y||x1==x+4 && y1==y||x1==x+5 && y1==y||x1==x+6 && y1==y||x1==x+7 && y1==y) && go==0)
            {
                ((Button)sender).Content=2.ToString();
                ((Button)sender).Tag=2;
                ((Button)vernut).Content="";
                ((Button)vernut).Tag=0;
            }
            else if(x1==x+1 && y1==y && go!=0)
            {
                ((Button)sender).Content=2.ToString();
                ((Button)sender).Tag=2;
                ((Button)vernut).Content="";
                ((Button)vernut).Tag=0;
                int a=Convert.ToInt32(belie.Text);
                a+=1;
                belie.Text=a.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Пока вы находитесь в самом начале, лучше сразу начать писать правильно. Вам нужно отделить слой отображения, т.е. визуальный интерфейс программы от логики игры, а логику игры следует писать согласно ООП, т.е. создайте класс `Фигура` на его базе создайте классы соотв. фигур игры, создайте класс для движка игры, определите в нем коллекции белых и черных фигур, коллекцию (список ходов в игре), коллекции выбывших из игры фигур, правила ходов и проч. Вам предстоит большая и сложная работа.

Comment: @Bulson Суть данной работы, это сделать шахматы без создания дополнительных классов, т.е. все действия только в рамках одного класса, связано это с тем, что сейчас я делаю работу так, а в следующем семестре подобное, но уже со знаниями ООП. Можете как-то помочь?

Comment: А как вы представляете себе запоминать позиции фигур, отличать одну фигуру от другой без использования доп.классов? Теоретически это возможно, но я честно не понимаю смысла в намеренном усложнение решения.

Comment: @Bulson это задание моего учебного заведения, с условием без доп классов, поэтому выкручиваюсь тегами в случае фигур. Мне понять бы как ограничить ходьбу той же ладьи, чтоб она не прыгала через свои фигуры

Comment: Видимо, нужно написать два метода: 1-й вычисляет все возможные ходы для выбранной фигуры, в зависимости от ее статуса и текущей позиции, 2-й производит фильтрацию из этих ходов с учетом свободных позиций на доске.

Comment: @Bulson ну я примерно к этому и пришел, но как только сделать эту самую фильтрацию для фигур вроде ладьи, я не особо понимаю. Так как по правилам шахмат она не должна перескакивать через свои фигуры при ходе, а в моем случае она перескакивает. И как вот ей задать параметр, что вот если перед ней стоит своя фигура,  то дальше нельзя?

Comment: 3 статуса у ячейки: 1) свободная, 2) занято чужой фигурой, 3) занято своей фигурой. Имея набор всех возможных ходов, отбраковываем те ходы которые пересекают ячейки с 3-им статусом.

Answer (score -1):

я вообщем могу тебе помочь я сделал реализацию примерно как и ты. Вообщем я накладываю картинки поверх кнопок и если фигура перемещается то удаляю ее на старом месте и переношу на новое. Пока сделал только ходы для ферзей и пешек. Сейчас думаю над реализацией шаха не можешь помочь? вот ввобщем ссылка на мой проект. https://github.com/AmpilGit/chess-wpf.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос